# Real-time priority problem with OpenAL / PipeWire after upgrade to Fedora 36

Tags: fedora, audio, pipewire

After a recent upgrade to Fedora 36 from Fedora 35, many video-conferencing / live-chatting applications don't work anymore.

In Telegram, I'm getting an error like this:

```
[ALSOFT] (EE) Failed to set real-time priority for thread: Operation not permitted (1)
```

Having dug deeper into this issue, it seems a permission problem with OpenAL, possibly PipeWire (which is what I use).
The error message is generated by this code: https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft/blob/openal-soft-1.21.0/alc/helpers.cpp#L503

As an effect no live conferencing / voice chat applications work anymore.

This seems to have been a problem in the past, at least I've found them being mentioned here and there in 2021 for distros like Arch and Gentoo, but not Fedora.

Where can I check and set permissions to fix this issue?
Is there perhaps a workaround?

I'm not exactly sure where to look for further logs, error prescriptions, etc. I'm also not sure where to even find settings like these permissions for PipeWire or OpenAL.